# Table getting locked after a batch job

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

We have an LDAP table and a daily batch job updating the table.
The batch job Renames the existing table at the end of the proc.
It has been running for 4 yrs but since 2-3 days, it is taking more han 30 minds to run and locks the LDAP table itself. 
The entire application goes down and we need to kill the session, however the batch completes successfully.
Please advise

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907783/oracle-11g-rename-guaranteed-to-be-atomic

Comment: Please consider to use partitioning and exchange partition statement.

Comment: Mayby there's something wrong with table name, which your batch script generate. Could You provide an example table name?

Comment: @UltraCommit: Doesn't seem to be the duplicate since we have no drop command.

Comment: @MichałM : Ex.: RENAME LDAP to LDAP_OLD.

but it has been running correctly till last week.
Could it be a data issue?

Comment: Hard to say, not much information. Of course it could be data issue... Mayby it is... 4years without problem and now...

Comment: Sounds like it's locked by another session. What is the rename session waiting on during that half hour?