# Reducing downtime - Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, partition

Here's the scenario I need help with:

I have a large Oracle table. This oracle table is being queried by mobile app users 1-10 times per second. This allows for very little down time of the table.

There is a backend process that refreshes all the data in the table, 1mio rows approximately. The process deletes * from the table, then inserts values from the source table. That's it.

The problem: this causes the table to be unavailable for too long (15 minutes).
I read about partition exchange, but all the examples I find deal with a certain partition range which doesn't apply to my problem.

My question: can I somehow refresh the data in a temp offline table and then just make that table my online/live table? That would just be a synonym/name swap, wouldn't it? Are there better methods?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Step 1: `DELETE FROM table`.  Step 2: `INSERT INTO table`.  Step 3: `COMMIT`.  No downtime.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907783/oracle-11g-rename-guaranteed-to-be-atomic

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Would the COMMIT statement not initiate writing the data to the table? In other words, wouldn't the COMMIT statement run for a while thereby causing downtime?

Comment: No, commits are basically instant.  All they do is write a marker saying "transaction xyz has been committed".  The data will have already been written to the table blocks and to the online redo logs with a transaction id of "xyz".  How that works exactly is beyond the scope of a comment, but it is worth learning.  The key point is that commits are effectively instant.

Comment: I agree with Matthew. Deleting and inserting may take 15 minutes, but until you COMMIT, users who hit the table (except the user doing the deletions and insertions) see the OLD version of the table. COMMIT is instantaneous. It essentially does exactly what you were thinking of doing "by hand".

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak's suggestion does assume that your UNDO tablespace is adequately sized, since any records that are amended by a transaction (i.e. all of them since your process is deleting all the records) are written to the UNDO tablespace which is what the other sessions need to look in to work out what the data looked like before the uncommitted transaction started. Once the transaction is committed, all sessions can then get the information direct from the table again. (It's more complicated than this, but that's essentially how it works.)

Comment: How often is the refresh?

Comment: And by the way, 15 mins for a million rows is pretty slow...

Comment: @BobC whether 15 min is slow for 1 mio rows depends on more than just the number of rows, doesn't it? But it was just an example, not the actual runtime. The refresh is performed sporadically, probably every other day.

Comment: Why refresh everything? Can't you just apply a delta instead? In fact why not use Replication or Streams?

Comment: @mpdegn It will depend on more than just the number of rows. But unless each row is a 100GB in length, then 15 mins is probably 2 orders of magnitude off.

Comment: How about have two tables, tab1 and tab2. Lets say tab1 has current data. Now you need to refresh, so load into tab2. Have you application use a view, which currently points to tab1. Once you need to switch, just redefine the view to point to tab2. Then you can truncate tab1, ready to load the next day. Each day you just flip flop between the two tables

Comment: @BobC That's what's currently implemented and what I am looking to replace.

Comment: So what is  the issue that you are having with that approach?